# Android Volley MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, android, http-post, android-volley, malformedurlexception

Using Volley i am trying to send POST headers and receive a StringRequest but I'm getting a RuntimeException Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol, but i have a protocol.

I send a cookie and a token that are correct

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpPost = new  HttpPost("http://ipServer:portServer/xxx/products.json?place_id=1");

        httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.addHeader("cookie", cookieTmp);
        httpPost.addHeader("X-CSRF-Token", tokenTmp);

StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, String.valueOf(httpPost),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                        MainActivity.class));
                        LoginActivity.this.finish();
                }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                L.m("not response");
                handleVolleyError(error);
```

And im getting this exception:

```
E/Volley: [1070] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@c9461c0
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@c9461c0
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
       Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@c9461c0
          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:589)
          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:486)
          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:435)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

The tests I perform in Postman work correctly. 
Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In between of coding you used two different codes, such as "get" and "add".

Please make it consistent.

First try it with this:

```
 httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 
 httpPost.addHeader("cookie", cookieTmp); 
 httpPost.addHeader("X-CSRF-Token", tokenTmp);
```

And then with this:

```
  httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 
 httpPost.setHeader("cookie", cookieTmp); 
 httpPost.setHeader("X-CSRF-Token", tokenTmp);
```

### Edited

[image: See error message on postman]

Comment: I'm sorry, I've written it wrong here.
I have it tested in both ways  and in both it generates the same error.
Thank you

I have edited the question to avoid confusion

Comment: Your url is not able to hit on server. See error on postman in my edited post

Comment: is a private server, I can not publish that data, for that reason I have hidden them to ask the question, but in my postman it works correctly. :)

Comment: But sir, your code is looking absouletly correct. Its not having any issue. I just to see your URL to check. Can you please on my personal id? its for your help only. if you dont then its really ok thanks

Comment: I can't sorry, this server is for a job, it's not my server and it also requires validation. First I validated correctly and then I get the id session, id name and token without problems. The server is monitored.

Comment: I have marked this answer as correct. I guess everything was a server problem and this has been the best answer.